# Удаление объектов внутри объекта без рекурсии

Tags: javascript

Есть объект:

```
var transformedObject = {
    data: [
        {
            id: 1,
            alias: 'Sport',
            type: 'group',
            favorites: [
                {
                    id: 70,
                    parentAlias: 'Sport',
                    parentId: 1,
                    type: 'item',
                    title: 'Soccer'
                },
                {
                    id: 50,
                    parentAlias: 'Sport',
                    parentId: 1,
                    type: 'item',
                    title: 'Tennis'
                },
            ]
        },
        {
           id: 2,
           alias: 'Region',
           type: 'item',
           favorites: [],
        }      
    ],
    ides: [1, 2, 70, 50]
}
```

Нужно найти и удалить объекты по `id` **без рекурсии**. Даже те объекты, которые находятся в массиве `favorites`.

Почему без рекурсии можно прочитать [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9474465/is-iteration-faster-than-recursion-or-just-less-prone-to-stack-overflows).

Моя функция для удалении обьектов которое мне не по душе и работает не правильно. Использовал библиотеку *lodash*

```
function deleteFromObject(id)
{
_.forIn(transformedObject.data, function(item, key){                          
     if (transformedObject.data[key].id == id ) {
         transformedObject.data.splice(key, 1)
     }
     else
     {
       if (transformedObject.data[key].type == 'group' && transformedObject.data[key].favorites.length > 0)
       {
          var childNodes = transformedObject.data[key].favorites;
          _.forIn(childNodes, function(child, ckey){
              if (childNodes[ckey]._id == id) {
                 transformedObject.data[ckey].favorites.splice(ckey, 1);
               }
         });
       }
      }

   });
}
```

Comment: Так всё же: если нужно удалить "объект с `id` 10", то этот "`id` 10" нужно искать и в массиве объектов `data`, и в каждом массиве `favorites`? Структура объекта фиксирована? И с чем у вас возникла проблема при решении задачи самостоятельно?

Comment: Боитесь переполнения стека?

Comment: @Ni55aN Честно говоря да, просто не могу реально организовать цикл   который бы нашел и удалил обьекты

Comment: Что вы сделали самостоятельно, и что не получилось?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Рекурсия - естественный способ решения этой задачи. Но если боитесь использовать рекурсию, можно симулировать рекурсию с помощью стека:

```js
function deleteObjWithId(obj, id) {
  var traversalStack = [obj];
  while (traversalStack.length) {
    var currentObj = traversalStack.pop();
    for (var key in currentObj) {
      var nextObj = currentObj[key];
      if (nextObj.id === id) {
        if (currentObj instanceof Array) {
          currentObj.splice(key, 1);
        }
        else
          delete currentObj[key];
      }
      else if (typeof nextObj === "object") {
        traversalStack.push(nextObj);
      }
    }
  }
  return obj;
}


var transformedObject = {
  data: [{
    id: 1,
    alias: 'Sport',
    type: 'group',
    favorites: [{
      id: 70,
      parentAlias: 'Sport',
      parentId: 1,
      type: 'item',
      title: 'Soccer'
    }, {
      id: 50,
      parentAlias: 'Sport',
      parentId: 1,
      type: 'item',
      title: 'Tennis'
    }, ]
  }, {
    id: 2,
    alias: 'Region',
    type: 'item',
    favorites: [],
  }],
  ides: [1, 2, 70, 50]
};
console.log(deleteObjWithId(transformedObject, 70));
```

Answer (score 0):

Создайте второй объект с айдишниками родителями, например:

```
{70: 1, 50: 1}
```

И потом делайте поиск, либо используйте принцип хеш таблиц, например вам нужно найти объект с `id = 70`, то у вас должен быть id – data.1.favorites.70 и при этом `favorites` нужно сделать тоже объектом, а не массивом.

Comment: Да при фиксированной структуре объекта можно и двойным циклом обойтись.

Comment: Спасибо большое, через другой обьект как этот {70: 1, 50: 1} могу легко удалить и добавить новые обьекты